# Android Studio not deploying latest builds of my app

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I am using Android Studio-1.0.1 with Genymotion virtual device emulator for app development.Of late,studio has started behaving erratically.
Whenever I make some changes in the layout or the java class files and deploy the application,it does not reflect the changes that I made.
I already tried to:
1.make/clean/build app
2.Uninstalled the app several times from the emulato
3.cleared genymotion cache,invalidated studio cache,and even deleted the build folder of my app to remove old builds,
but it still does not help.
Is there anything else that I can do to solve this problem,and what is its possible cause in the first place?

Comment: sometimes perform __Tools --> Android --> Sync Project with Gradle Files__ helps